# Skipping threads based on parameter, then returning to them later

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, locking, semaphore

I have a method that takes in a value and if a condition is met the action shouldn't run for 24 hours. But when it stops I want to run other threads that don't met that condition.

In this example I have 30 threads made at the beginning of the program. Once I make 5 pieces of cheese I need to stop because that's too much cheese. What would be great is if there was a place to send threads that can't be acted on until time is run out while the others are running. Task.Delay even with Wait does not seem to be effective here.

Here's me code sample:

```
//Stop making cheese when you have enough for the day but continue making others
  public void madeEnoughToday(string cheese)
    {
//Find how much cheese is made based on cheese type.
            DataGridViewRow row = cheeseGV.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(r => 
r.Cells["Cheese"].Value.ToString().Equals(cheese))
                .First();
            if (row.Cells["MadeToday"].Value.Equals(row.Cells["Perday"].Value))
            {
                Task.Delay(30000).Wait();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to pause thread execution, I use another thread (global variable, or another implementation) - call `Thread.Join()` method for the second instance of the thread.

```
Thread tPause; // global var

private void MyThreadFunc()
{
    // do something
    if (pauseCondition)
    {
        tPause=new Thread(PauseThread);
        tPause.Start();
        tPause.Join(); // You can specify needed milliseconds, or TimeSpan
        // the subsequent code will not be executed until tPause.IsAlive == true
        // IMPORTANT: if tPause == null during Join() - an exception occurs
    }
}
private void PauseThread()
{
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); // You can specify needed milliseconds, or TimeSpan
}

private void Main()
{
    // any actions  
    Thread myThread=new Thread(MyThreadFunc);
    myThread.Start();
    // any actions

}
```

There are many ways of this realization.
If you want to continue the thread execution, you can call the `Thread.Abort()` method for the pause thread instance, or use the sophisticated construction of function for the pause thread.